# Using new Android Youtube API and extending Service

Tags: android, api, service, background, youtube

I am trying to build an application using the new Android Youtube API that will play when the application is not in the foreground. To achieve background play, I would like to embed the player into a service. I have tried this both with the YouTubePlayerActivity and YouTubePlayerFragment and both stop playback when the application is not in the foreground. Has anyone been able to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: After a quick look in the API: I dont believe that the api is supporting this